# Label is out of bounds of cell

Tags: ios, autolayout

My label inside cell looks like this

[image]

My code for constraints is like this

```
    repoName.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).active = true
    repoName.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10).active = true

    descriptionTextTop = descriptionText.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(repoName.bottomAnchor, constant: 10)
    descriptionTextTop!.active = true
    descriptionText.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).active = true
    descriptionText.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).active = true
```

it tableview I have

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
```

Why does this happen ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure the label has top and bottom margin constraints, against the cell

2) Tell the table view to use auto dimension: `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

3) You may also want to set the label's vertical content compression resistance priority to 1000

And it should work

BTW, any reasons why you are adding constraints programmatically instead of doing it in Interface Builder?